# Split number string

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have that string 12345b with out any space. How can I split it in one vector?
For example, I read from keyboard that string 12345b and I want to split it to have for example possibility to make something like that myVar[0] to obtain first character. But don't tell me about function charAt because I know about that but I don't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try :

```
char[] myChars = "12345b".toCharArray();
System.out.print(myChars[2]); // Prints 3
```